# boost:uuid into char * without std::string

Tags: c++, boost, uuid, stdstring

I am trying to convert a boost UUID to a `char *` without having to use `std::string` at all.

I mostly modified the `to_string` method from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp to my own version. However, it fails on certain UUIDs.

Here is my modification:

```
#include <boost/uuid/string_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>

using UUID = boost::uuids::uuid;

static constexpr std::size_t UUID_STR_LEN = 37;

inline char uuid_byte_to_char(size_t i)
{
    if (i <= 9) {
        return static_cast<char>('0' + i);
    } else {
        return static_cast<char>('a' + (i - 10));
    }
}

inline void uuid_to_cstr(UUID const& uuid, char out[UUID_STR_LEN])
{
    std::size_t out_i = 0;
    std::size_t dash_i = 0;
    for (UUID::const_iterator it_data = uuid.begin(); it_data != uuid.end(); ++it_data, ++dash_i) {
        const size_t hi = ((*it_data) >> 4) & 0x0F;
        out[out_i++] = uuid_byte_to_char(hi);

        const size_t lo = (*it_data) & 0x0F;
        out[out_i++] = uuid_byte_to_char(lo);

        if (dash_i == 3 || dash_i == 5 || dash_i == 7 || dash_i == 9) {
            out[out_i++] += '-';
        }
    }
    out[UUID_STR_LEN - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    UUID uuid(uuid_generator());
    char uuid_cstr(UUID_STR_LEN];
    uuid_to_str(uuid uuid_cstr);
    std::cout << uuid_cstr << "\n";
}
```

So if the UUID was `cd0fa728-e7d6-4578-9450-7beb284e0103` for example this works fine.

However, for `0cf31c43-7621-407c-94d6-6d593bae96e8` what I actually end up getting is `0cf31c43-7621�407cQ94d6-6d593bae96e8`.

What's the problem in my code? As far as I'm aware, my char manipulations mimic what the std::string is doing minus the temporary copies due to the constant appending. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `std::string`?

Comment: What temporary copies? That header does `result.reserve(36);` all over the place.

Comment: @PeterRuderman Avoiding memory allocations

Comment: Avoiding the unnecessary dynamic allocation is noble though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right. This still allocates memory. I'm trying to do it all on the stack as this is used in pretty fast code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buffer `char uuid_cstr[UUID_STR_LEN];` was allocated onto stack so it has garbage values, all elements in buffer has some initial value probably not 0.

1) You can set all items to zero by

```
char uuid_cstr[UUID_STR_LEN];
memset (uuid_cstr,0,UUID_STR_LEN);
```

then the following statement can work

```
out[out_i++] += '-';
```

2) Or use the assignment

```
out[out_i++] = '-';
```

Comment: I just needed an extra set of eyes on this.. thanks for catching that! Explains why the errors always appeared at the dash.

Comment: `char uuid_cstr[UUID_STR_LEN] = {};`